# Are this query identical? Not exist and left outer join formulation

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, not-exists

I want to take every record of ENI_MONITOR which is orphan. In ENI_FLUSSI_HUB the corresponding record should not exists. Are both te formulation correct? How does left outer join thinks?

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (mon, 10) */
       COUNT(1)
FROM   B
WHERE  B.mon_flag_ann = 'N'
       AND NOT EXISTS
           (
               SELECT /*+  PARALLEL (c, 10)  */
                      1
               FROM   A
               WHERE  B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO = A.flh_id_messaggio
                      AND B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO = A.flh_tipo_processo_cod
                      AND A.FLH_FLAG_ANN = 'N'
           );


SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (mon, 10) parallel (c 10) */
       COUNT(DISTINCT MON_MONITORAGGIO_ID)
FROM   B,
       A
WHERE  B.mon_flag_ann = 'N'
       AND B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO = A.flh_id_messaggio(+)
       AND B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO = A.flh_tipo_processo_cod(+)
       AND A.FLH_FLAG_ANN(+) = 'N'
       AND A.flh_id_messaggio(+) IS NULL
```

Comment: @Glk25 . . . Does the field `flh_id_messaggio` take on NULL values?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no. All this fields are not nullable.

Answer (score 1):

The two are functionally equivalent, except perhaps in the case when the code is NULL.   SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  The syntax describes the result set, not (necessarily) how the processing is being done.

here are multiple ways to write a query such as this (including a `not in` version).  How the queries get executed depends on the path chosen by the engine.  [Here](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67781/c20c_joi.htm) are some options.  If you Google, there are more examples of specific performance timings for different formulations of the query.

The second structure is not a good way to write an outer join query.  Here is the preferred syntax:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (mon, 10) parallel (c 10) */
       COUNT(DISTINCT MON_MONITORAGGIO_ID)
FROM   B left outer join
       A
       on B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO = A.flh_id_messaggio and
          B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO = A.flh_tipo_processo_cod and
          A.FLH_FLAG_ANN = 'N'
WHERE  B.mon_flag_ann = 'N' and
       A.flh_id_messaggio IS NULL
```

Comment: The same as below, they are not equivalent, or *your* SQL is not equivalent. I say that because you movede the ̉`̉is null` from the (+) to the ̉`wherẻ`.

Comment: @Plouf! - this is closer to the OP's first query. If there is not a match in `A` on the outer join conditions, then when the `where` clause is evaluated `A.flh_id_messaggio` is `null` - which is equivalent to `not exists`. But no, the OP's two queries are not equivalent, because the second is comparing `A.flh_id_messaggio` against both `null` and `B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO, and it can't be equal to something and `null` at the same time. I think that's what you meant in the other comment.

Comment: @Plouf! I don't understand very well. I can say my formulation of the second query is different from the first query. But I cannot understan why. Gordon Linoff formulation works? Why my formulation doesn't?

Comment: @AlexPoole can you answer not in a comment? The two statement are not equivalent? I can't imagine why.

Answer (score 1):

They are different, but it's easier to see why when converted to ASNSI join syntax, as Gordon Linoff showed. In that form your second query becomes:

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (mon, 10) parallel (c 10) */
       COUNT(DISTINCT MON_MONITORAGGIO_ID)
FROM   B
LEFT JOIN A
    ON A.flh_id_messaggio = B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO
    AND A.flh_tipo_processo_cod = B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO
    AND A.FLH_FLAG_ANN = 'N'
    AND A.flh_id_messaggio IS NULL
WHERE  B.mon_flag_ann = 'N'
```

The outer join condition includes both `A.flh_id_messaggio = B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO` **and** `A.flh_id_messaggio IS NULL`, which cannot both be true. (Even if `B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO` was null, this would fail as you can't use `=` to compare nulls). So the outer join can never find a match, might as well be omitted, and you'll therefore count all distinct `MON_MONITORAGGIO_ID` values from `B`.

However, if you move the `IS NULL` check down to the `WHERE` clause (as Gordon did):

```
SELECT /*+ PARALLEL (mon, 10) parallel (c 10) */
       COUNT(DISTINCT MON_MONITORAGGIO_ID)
FROM   B
LEFT JOIN A
    ON A.flh_id_messaggio = B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO
    AND A.flh_tipo_processo_cod = B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO
    AND A.FLH_FLAG_ANN = 'N'
WHERE  B.mon_flag_ann = 'N'
    AND A.flh_id_messaggio IS NULL
```

... the then outer join condition can find matches. If it does not find a match, when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated then `A.flh_id_messaggio` will indeed now be `null`, so this is like your original `NOT EXISTS`.

There is also an assumption that MON_MONITORAGGIO_ID is unique, which may well be the case. But since you're only counting when there is no match, I don't think you need the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: However, is it right to say that in my formulation the left outer joins takes every record of ENI_MONITOR with every other record of the ENI_FLUSSI_HUB. Cartesian Product. And then refines the search by the following rule: A.flh_id_messaggio = B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO
    AND A.flh_tipo_processo_cod = B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO OR the following rule, b.rowid is null?

Comment: @Gik25 - no, it doesn't form a cartesian product; the old-style Oracle-specific `(+)` notation still does an outer join based on the join conditions, particularly `A.flh_id_messaggio = B.MON_ID_MESSAGGIO` and `A.flh_tipo_processo_cod = B.MON_COD_TP_PROCESSO`. But it also makes `A.flh_id_messaggio IS NULL` a join condition, and that can never be met; my (and Gordon's) version makes that a *filter* after the left join, not part of the join itself.